Angular - Resolver - ComponentStore
In angular 17, with ngrx, I have a resolver and once the page is resolved, I have a component with a component store.
Here is my resolver:
export const timeRecordingTypeResolver: ResolveFn<TTimeRecordingTypes | null> = () => {
  const $store = inject(Store);
  $store.dispatch(HomeActions.fetchTimeRecordingType());
  return $store.select(homeFeature.selectTimeRecordingTypes).pipe(
    filter(types => types !== null),
    take(1)
  );
};

In the ctor of my component store, I initialize my component store state:
constructor() {
    super(attendanceHistoryCardInitialState);
    console.log('AttendanceHistoryCardComponentStore constructor');
    console.log('state', this.get());
  }

If I have my resolver, this.get(); throws an error:
Error: AttendanceHistoryCardComponentStore has not been initialized yet. Please make sure it is initialized before updating/getting.
    at AttendanceHistoryCardComponentStore.assertStateIsInitialized (ngrx-component-store.mjs:349:19)
    at AttendanceHistoryCardComponentStore.get (ngrx-component-store.mjs:262:14)
    at new AttendanceHistoryCardComponentStore (attendance-history.card.component-store.ts:90:31)
    at NodeInjectorFactory.AttendanceHistoryCardComponentStore_Factory [as factory] (attendance-history.card.component-store.ts:21:50)
    at getNodeInjectable (core.mjs:5984:44)
    at searchTokensOnInjector (core.mjs:5911:16)
    at lookupTokenUsingNodeInjector (core.mjs:5860:34)
    at getOrCreateInjectable (core.mjs:5772:23)
    at ɵɵdirectiveInject (core.mjs:11050:19)
    at ɵɵinject (core.mjs:1106:60)

If I comment my resolver, this.get works well, the component state is initialized and I don't have an error.
For now, I don't have http calls, so to simulate low network, in my fetchData method in my service (called in the effect of the action, disptached by the resolver), I add a pipe(delay(1500)).
If a remove this delay and uncomment my resolver, this.get() works well too.
I don't understand this issue with my resolver/delay/component store. Why my component store initialization doesn't work well if my resolver take some times (delay) ?
Can you help me please, I would like to know the reason of this behavior.
I try a lot of thing but I don't find a solution to this issue.

I see some potential issues, but first, what is the type of 'types': filter(types => types !== null)?

@mat.hudak Types = export type TTimeRecordingTypes = Array<ITimeRecordingType>; where ITimeRecordingType is a simple intefrace representing a type of "time-recording". And the selector returns types which is initially null

It kind of looks like your resolver manages to get pass types !== null. Don't you have a reducer tied to fetchTimeRecordingType action that sets the array to an empry array? Just an idea, in your case I would switch from resolvers to Router Store, see https://ngrx.io/guide/router-store. If I have more time I'll try to post a possible solution

@mat.hudak I found a solution. I use ngrxOnStoreInit() in my component store and I intialize a boolean once I reach this method. On my html templace I surround whole code by un @if that checks if componentStore is initialized.
I don't know if this is the best way but i foudn only that. I checked for the router store but it was not resolve the issue. Thanks for your help.
